# Pros and Cons of Hibernate 4?

Tags: hibernate

Could someone list the key differences between Hibernate 3 vs Hibernate 4?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many articles: [Hibernate 4 Release](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/01/hibernate-4-released/). A good insight could also be found on Steve's blog: [In Relation To...](http://relation.to/Bloggers/Steve).

If you are worrying about Hibernate 3 migration to Hibernate 4, you should read this Steve's article: [Hibernate Core Migration Guide: 4.0](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40).